PHP 8.2-FPM PHPRC Not Overriding Loaded Configuration File
I am using PHP 8.2-FPM with Nginx, and I am trying to set a custom php.ini file using the PHPRC environment variable. I can see that $_SERVER['PHPRC'] is correctly set in the PHP Variables section when I run phpinfo(), but the Loaded Configuration File still points to the default /etc/php/8.2/cgi/php.ini.
My Nginx Conf.
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;

        fastcgi_param PHPRC /var/www/website/php.ini;
        fastcgi_param PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR /var/www/website;
    }

Setting PHPRC via Nginx configuration: I added the following to my Nginx configuration within the PHP location block:
fastcgi_param PHPRC /var/www/website/php.ini;
fastcgi_param PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR /var/www/website
PHP-FPM pool configuration: In the PHP-FPM pool configuration (/etc/php/8.2/fpm/pool.d/www.conf), I added:
php_admin_value[PHPRC] = /var/www/website/php.ini
php_admin_value[PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR] = /var/www/website
Restarting services: After making these changes, I restarted both Nginx and PHP-FPM:
sudo systemctl restart nginx 
sudo systemctl restart php8.2-fpm
What I expected:
I expected phpinfo() to show the custom php.ini located at /var/www/website/php.ini under Loaded Configuration File. What’s happening:
In the PHP Variables section of phpinfo(), I see:
$_SERVER['PHPRC'] /var/www/website/php.ini
However, the Loaded Configuration File still points to:
/etc/php/8.2/cgi/php.ini

PHPRC and PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR should be environment variables, I am not sure if fastcgi_param has the same functionality.

I don't know but when i export PHPRC on terminal, it works with php -i command.
root@None:/etc# export PHPRC="/var/www/website/php.ini"
root@None:/etc# php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File"
Loaded Configuration File => /var/www/website/php.ini

Does exporting PHPRC work for phpfpm?

No, only works on php cli.

You need to check the start command of php8.2-fpm service to see if there is a -c or -n option that overrides the configuration file.

I have tried using -n flag. That didn’t work either. So i decided to use fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE in NGINX to change values.

You can't set environment variables using fastcgi_param directive. However you can try env directive to do it:
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;

        env PHPRC=/var/www/website/php.ini;
        env PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR=/var/www/website;
    }

